# Fetching results in PDO WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I'm trying to fetch a number where the user ID = the session ID.  For example, if the User ID = 1, I want to fetch the amount of bets the user has.

I tried using MySQL's COUNT but it's not giving the proper result.  What am I doing wrong?

![][1]http://puu.sh/3KYVf.png

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

    $selectTotalBets = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid");

        $selectTotalBets->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));

            $TotalBetsRow = $selectTotalBets->fetch();

                $userTotalBets = $TotalBetsRow['uid'];



?>
```

Comment: `COUNT(*) as totalBets` then you can get it from `$TotalBetsRow['totalBets'];`

Comment: try with `$userTotalBets = $TotalBetsRow['COUNT(*)']` or `$selectTotalBets->rowCount()`

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Do I replace totalBets with `uid`?

Comment: @Akam both returned nothing.

Comment: or no, sorry it returned 1 when it should return 47 because the UID 1 has 47 bets.

Comment: run the query with PHPMyAdmin and verify the result

Comment: Run my MySQL query inside of the prepared statement?

Comment: If a visual helps - http://puu.sh/3KYVf.png as you can see it there's 13 there, but if the thirteenth was uid = 2 I'd want it to show 12 of course.  How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by lawrence -

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
session_start();

    $selectTotalBets = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `totalBets` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid");

        $selectTotalBets->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));

            $TotalBetsRow = $selectTotalBets->fetch();

                $userTotalBets = $TotalBetsRow['totalBets'];

?>
```

Comment: Read this: If a visual helps - puu.sh/3KYVf.png as you can see it there's 13 there, but if the thirteenth was uid = 2 I'd want it to show 12 of course. How can I do this? – user2609179 31 mins ago

Comment: Did you try running the same query in phpMyAdmin as suggested by Akam?

Comment: Yeah it returned the same thing.  did you read my comment?  Should explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I read your comments. If your table is called "users" and structured as depicted in your image then "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `totalBets` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = 1" will return 13

Comment: Are you sure the table name is "users" and not "user_bids" or something else? That does not look like a typical "users" table to me.

Comment: Oh crap the table name is bets...  But it's still returning string(1) "1" after changing it...

Comment: Please execute "SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalBets FROM bets WHERE uid = 1" in phpMyAdmin and then pop up a full screenshot.

Comment: Oh my god..  I'm so sorry, was editing the wrong file.  Thanks for your help anyway..

Answer (score 0):

include_once('db.php');
session_start();

```
$selectTotalBets = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(bid) AS `totalBets` FROM `users` WHERE `uid` = :uid");

    $selectTotalBets->execute(array(':uid' => $_SESSION['uid']));

        $TotalBetsRow = $selectTotalBets->fetch();

            $userTotalBets = $TotalBetsRow['totalBets'];
```

User Max() for getting the maximum value.